# Getting an MVC DropDownList to show the selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have this code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCouponsAppointment",
    Model.Coupons.Select(a => new SelectListItem {
                                    Text = a.Name,
                                    Value = a.CouponId.ToString(),
                                    Selected = (a.CouponId == Model.CouponForAppointmentReminders.CouponId)
                        }), 
    "None",
    new { @class = "normalcell" })
```

This has worked for ages.  Now, it throws an error, which a google tells me is because I am not allowed to call ToString on an entity that is being mapped to a class ( this class has not changed, so I am at a loss how it worked before ).  So I added a property called CouponIdStr, which is a string representation.  This does not work ( blows up b/c the property is not mapped to the DB ).  I tried making value equal string.Empty + a.CouponId ( as C# would concatenate that as a string ).  It blows up.

So I tried this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCouponsAppointment",
    new SelectList(Model.Coupons,
        "Name",
        "CouponId",
        Model.CouponForAppointmentReminders.CouponId),
    "None",
    new { @class = "normalcell" })
```

This works, but does not show the selected item.  Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: In your second code block I cannot see Selected = (a.CouponId == Model.CouponForAppointmentReminders.CouponId)   How do you say to @Html.DropDownList  to select something then?

Comment: You're missing what's happening.  The SelectList constructor takes a parameter for the selected value.  It turns out I had the name and couponId the wrong way around.  I tried to post an answer, but SO does not let me do that ( I click 'answer' and browsed away, so I didn't see the response ), so that's why this is sitting here without a resolution, despite my finding one.  Still would like to know why there is no way for the first block of code to work, that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1. Create a ViewModel that has the selected value

step 2. In that ViewModel have the list of items you want in the select list

```
public class ViewModel {      
   public int Selected {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Option> Options {get;set;}
}
```

step 3. In your view, use the DisplayFor method

```
Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Selected, new SelectList(Model.Options, "Id", "Display"));
```

There you have it, when the dropdown renders, it will have the selected value selected!

Good Luck!